# Is this number in $O(\log(n))$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, logarithms, asymptotics

Is this number $\big[\log(n) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (\log(j) - (j+1)(\log(j+1)) + j \log(j) +1)\big] \in O(\log(n))$?

I simplified it to $\big[\log(n) + \sum_{j=1}^n (-\log(n+1) - j(\log(n)) + 1)\big]$.

Comment: Single *numbers* are not in O of anything. This is a *sequence* (indexed by $n$), of course

Comment: The answer is pretty clear once you simplify that sum.

Comment: Ah, right @HagenvonEitzen -- thanks for the simple reminder...

Comment: Functions, not numbers, are members of any $O(f)$.

Comment: How could I further simplify @AntonioVargas?  Hmm...I have simplified a great deal already to arrive at this number, e.g., used telescoping sums...

Comment: First try splitting it into three sums, one for each term.

Comment: Ok, will try now - thanks so much @AntonioVargas ...

Comment: Thanks @BrianO for the reminder...

Comment: Hi @AntonioVargas, I get $\large log(n) -nlog(n+1) - \frac {n(n+1)}{2}log(n) + n$ ...

Comment: ...so is it actually in $O(n)$, @AntonioVargas?  (I really need it to be in $O(log(n))$, though...

Comment: @user296012 It is $O(n^2 \log(n))$. But you might have made a mistake in simplifying if it must be $\log(n)$, so please post the entire proces of going from your original expression to this you got. That is also encouraged in general, since it looks like we're doing your entire homework here, instead of just doing the last step, and that prevents many users form answering. And, even more important, we can point out mistakes or things that can be done quicker in your approach.

Comment: Hi @wythagoras, nice username :-)  here's my work, before simplifying and possibly using telescoping sums incorrectly:  I have the number $log(n) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} [log(j) - log(j+1)(j+1) + log(j)(j) + 1]$ What do you think?  Is this is $O(log(n))$?  Thanks,

Comment: @user296012 Thank you. It is generally better to do this in an edit, so I edited it in your question for you.

Comment: The expression in your last comment **is** $O(\log n)$, but, as wythagoras said, the one in your original question is not :).

Comment: Hi @AntonioVargas it really is??!!  That means I can go home!! Oh gosh ...it's 4:30 am here...how can you tell it's really $O(log(n))$?  I ummm simplified the number a bit from my last comment but don't see it, though.  How should I go about simplifying it / seeing that it is $O(log(n))$?  Thanks so much,

Comment: When I go for telescoping sums to simplify, the sequence doesn't appear to be in $O(log(n))$ anymore, for some reason @AntonioVargas ...

Comment: Well, I asked my computer, which said that $$\log(n) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} [\log(j) - (j+1)\log(j+1) + j \log(j) + 1] = \frac{\log(n)}{2} + \frac{\log(2\pi)}{2} - 1 + O(1/n),$$ but I don't think it would be that hard to find a proof. I'm in the same time zone as you but I might not be able to put together an answer until tomorrow. Hopefully someone else can do something sooner for you.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much @AntonioVargas.  I would love to see a derivation, if you have time tomorrow :-)  I found a proof but the estimate is not as sharp:  it gives $O(n)$ instead.  Have a great night!  zzZZZzzzzz ...

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (\log(j) - (j+1)(\log(j+1)) + j \log(j) +1) &= \\ \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} ( - (j+1)(\log(j+1)) + (j+1) \log(j) +1) &= \\ \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} ( (j+1)(\log(j)-\log(j+1)) +1) \end{align*}

So I don't think your simplification is correct.

Now use $\ln(n) = H_n + \gamma + \frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$. This gives $$\ln(n)-\ln(n+1) = H_n - H_{n+1} - \frac1{2n+2} -\frac1{2n}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right) = \frac{-1}{n+1}+O\left(\frac1{n^2}\right)$$

Thus $$(n+1)(\ln(n)-\ln(n+1)) = -1 +O\left(\frac1n\right)$$

$$(n+1)(\ln(n)-\ln(n+1))+1 = O\left(\frac1n\right)$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} ( (j+1)(\log(j)-\log(j+1)) +1) = O\left(\ln(n)\right)$$

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} ( (j+1)(\log(j)-\log(j+1)) +1) = O\left(\log(n)\right)$$

$$\log(n) + \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} ( (j+1)(\log(j)-\log(j+1)) +1) = O\left(\log(n)\right)$$

Comment: Hi @wythagoras, is your expansion of $ln(n)$ ... a Taylor expansion?  If so, then it seems a little strange to be expanding in powers of a discrete variable $n$ rather than in powers of a continuous variable $x$.  Also, did you get it from direct computation, e.g., compute the Taylor coefficients, or is it some special formula that should just be memorized?  Because as far as I've known, regarding logarithms, I have only ever Taylor expanded $ln(1+x)$ or $ln(1-x)$, and never $ln(x)$ or $ln(n)$.  What do you think?  Thanks for your time,

Comment: @LebronJames The series I used can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number. It is not a Taylor expansion.

Comment: Ok, got it -- thanks so much for your write-up @wythagoras.  I solved my problem by finally learning the Abel summation formula - and gave up using brute force estimates like the one you gave.  I will move on now, though, due to time constraints :-( Hope to hear from you soon.  Have a great night :-)